# How to add new post using a form to categories when categories are using as menu

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts

I have a form to create new post and I pass my post_category into post creating array, but it not insert into that category , it insert into Uncategorized category.And I want to see the post using the menu that I created using categories.

I pass may data to following array to create post.Its working but it insert post into Uncategorized(default) category.
any solution?

```
 $post = array('post_type'=>'post',
              'post_author'=>$author,
              'post_status'=>'publish',
              'post_title'  => 'Test Title',
              'post_category' => '679'
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in following line

> 'post_category' => array('679')

Use `'post_category' => array(679)` without single quote.

Answer (score 1):

The post_category parameter has to be an array, try this:

```
$post = array('post_type'=>'post',
 'post_author'=>$author,
 'post_status'=>'publish',
 'post_title'  => 'Test Title',
 'post_category' => array('679')
);
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Parameters

If that doesn't work for you, try using category_name:

```
'category_name' => 'category_name',
```

Comment: unfortunately I have Sub categories with same name under different main categories

Comment: OK, but did adding the category ID as an array work?